# IIS Conditional authentication with the Windows Authentication module

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I have an unusual situation in which authentication isn't necessary but where learning the user-id via windows authentication under certain conditions would be useful.

To give some context, I want to be able to require windows authentication when the user-agent matches certain conditions, but not require authentication in other conditions. With only some familiarity with asp.net and iis I suspect I am missing an easy way of accomplishing this. So far I've looked into writing a module that checks the user-agent and then adds the WindowsAuthenticationModule if the conditions are met - but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions the best way to auth or not auth on the value of the user-agent?

Answer (score 0):

If you setup IIS to use windows authentication, you should be able to do something like the following code snippet.

However, as you may guess from the comments in the code, I would advise against it.  The User Agent is **easily** spoofed - so any authentication checks you do based on it can also easily be bypassed.  The same holds true for pretty much *anything* that comes across in an http header (e.g., basing authentication on http referrer is also a bad idea).

```
string windowsUserName = null;

var currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

//NOT SECURE - easily spoofed!
if (currentContext.Request.UserAgent == "Some special user agent")
{
    if (!currentContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
        || currentContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType != "Windows")
    {
        throw new SecurityException(@"You are not authorized, but you can easily 
hack this application by modifying the user agent that you send to the server.")
    }

    windowsUserName = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

So in short, even if the above works, **don't do it**.  You really need to completely rethink how you are authenticating your application.

If, as you seem to indicate in the first sentence of your question, this is *purely* informational, then it *may* be ok (e.g. if it is just for debugging purposes).  However, it would *not* be suitable e.g. for auditing or restricting access to any resources, and you must be extremely careful that this code doesn't get reused in any real security context.

Comment: You may also be interested in http://cybersecurity.ieee.org/center-for-secure-design.html

Comment: i am not missing the point of how weak it is to base a security decision on a request header. it is a content tailoring problem, not an authentication problem. my question was so heavily bastardized by the stackoverflow editors that it misses the original point of my question.

pseudo code...
`if special-user-agent then:
  if not authenticated then:
     - respond with http 401 by "invoking" the built-in WindowsAuthenticationModule 
  else:
    - serve the content, tailored to the user-id
else:
 - serve the content`

Comment: .. the problem then becomes, how do you invoke/require/inject a built in auth module within a handler or module. the WindowsAuthenticationModule does not allow subclasses. i think it would be possible to accomplish what i require if it could be subclassed. thanks for your answer by the way Nathan.